# Kendo Angular 2 Grid Data Formatting

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Ok... hopefully I'll figure this out soon but thought I'd ask the community. :)

I have my angular 2 grid basically running well now, but I can't figure out how to prevent column data from wrapping and extending the row height. I know there were various tricks to use CSS and "elipsis" properties in previous iterations of the grid, but I havn't had any luck so far with the angular 2 kendo implementation.

Any ideas? I have 3 or 4 columns that I need to keep to a maximum width. I don't want the rows to grow larger than one line of text.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying something like this (which isn't working):

<kendo-grid-column field="Category" title="Category" [class]="{'myClass': true}">

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds my thread... I solved this by changing the CSS for the TD elements in the kendo grid. (It took me a while to track this down as it was not apparent which style was not wrapping).

Anyway, here is the style that makes the cells use ellipsis truncation:

```css
// Make sure table cells do NOT wrap (will use ellipsis by default)
.k-grid td { 
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```